# How can I sync external servers to point to an AWS ec2 server running aws time sync chrony

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, chrony

I have setup an EC2 to use the time sync and want to use it as an 'NTP' server. I have setup the security group to allow all traffic in on 80,443, and 123 for now to test the configuration. It's in a public subnet with an elastic IP. There is also a route53 record. How can I configure external servers to point 169.254.169.123\or the route53 record to sync the time? Is this even possible?

I tried with my Mac to sync time by pointing to the elastic IP\route53 record without success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Hau

Comment: What’s the reason for not using a public NTP server like `pool.ntp.org`?

Comment: Have you confirmed allowing port 123/udp?  NTP does not use 123/tcp.

Comment: I can definitely use NTP but since I'm on AWS and they have a service, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/keeping-time-with-amazon-time-sync-service/, I was wondering if anyone has attempted or is currently using it as a time service like NTP....UDP port 123 is open.